# C-style for statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future

Tags: ios, xcode, for-loop, swift2

Anyone came across this?

I ve got a nice little loop but it seems to get a warning.

```
 for(;;nimages++)
```

Comment: "nice"? That loop would be bad code in every language I know. It works but it is not nice.

Comment: It was proposed and accepted to remove the ++ and -- operators from the Swift language in an upcoming release. For a full explanation you can reference the following link: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-remove-pre-post-inc-decrement.md C-Style loops will also be deprecated in the near future: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md

Comment: @DerekLee can you answer the question so I can accept your answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It was proposed and accepted to remove the ++ and -- operators from the Swift language in an upcoming release](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-remove-pre-post-inc-decrement.md), therefore the warning you're seeing is to help you avoid these types of constructs in your code before it is removed. (Please reference the link for a full explanation as well as the advantages and disadvantages that they provide.)

Please note that C-Style loops will also be deprecated in the near future according to the following proposal: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md

Not knowing exactly what kind of logic you need to implement I don't feel confident recommending a solution, however in accordance with the above proposals I would recommend that you may want to become familiar with the Swift `for-in` and `stride` statements. Or, as another person recommended, using a `while` loop may also be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

What's the question? The entire error message is

> C-style for statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of
>   Swift

You could replace this with something like

```
while true {
    // loop body
    nimages += 1
}
```

Finally, if you know the number of iterations you want, you can use a for-in loop:

```
for nimages in 0..<maxImages { /* loop body */ }
```

Comment: Sorry the question is: replace it with what?

Comment: I hit [return] too soon :)

Comment: I want to count down, but swift doesn't accept for idx in count-1..0, which is easily supported in the "deprecated" version.  Do you know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[C Style For loops are deprecated](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md) and [incrementing decrementing like these i++ , i-- also deprecated](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-remove-pre-post-inc-decrement.md)

Therefore couldn't be used this type of loops anymore

```
let myArray = ["one","two","three","four","five","six"]

for var i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++ {
    print(myArray[i])
}
```

**Instead of use above syntax, we can use this**

```
let myArray = ["one","two","three","four","five","six"]

for i in 0..<myArray.count {
    print(myArray[i])
}
```

**And also this**

```
for i in 0...myArray.count-1 {
    print(myArray[i])
}
```

If you are not familiar with **Range Operators** and **Half-Open Range Operators** this is the time 
([Document Link)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID73)

**Range Operators**

> The closed range operator (a...b) defines a range that runs from a to b, and includes the values a and b. The value of a must not be greater than b.

**Half-Open Range Operators**

> The half-open range operator (a..<b) defines a range that runs from a to b, but does not include b.

Answer (score 0):

For `index--` style

```
 for index in 10.stride(to: 0, by: -1) {
      print(index)//This is 10, 9, 8, ... 1 NOT 0
  }
```

For `index++` style

```
for index in 0..<10 {
}
```